# Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces and let A ∈ B($X$) (Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $X$), B ∈ B($Y$). How to show that A × B ∈ B($X\times Y$)?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let X be a topological space.  All that I know is Borel $\sigma$ algebra on X is the smallest $\sigma$ algebra generated by $T_X$ i.e. set of all open sets in X. Is there any other characterization of Borel $\sigma$ algebra on X? or we can show the above assertion using the definition only.

Answer (score 2):

You can show that the set $\{A\times B: A\in \mathbb{B}(X),B\in \mathbb{B}(Y)\}$ is $\sigma$-algebra that contains the open sets of $A\times B$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for finite products, the product topology is generated by products of open sets. Hence you only need to use the definition to show what you need.